# TYPO3 HMENU doesn't shows parent Level pages

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, typo3, typoscript

I want to make a Header menu, witch should be static through all subpages. At Home page I have this typoscript and works fine

```
//this is a subpart 
MENU_HEADER = COA
  MENU_HEADER {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul> 
        entryLevel = 0
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            //expAll = 1
            target = _top
            NO = 1
            NO {
              allWrap = <li class="list1">|</li>
              stdWrap.innerWrap = <strong><img src="fileadmin/templates/img/header/menu-list1-icon.png" width="45px" height="50px;" alt=""></strong><span>|</span>
            }
        }
    }
```

In my subpages I have the following typoscript code:

```
MENU_PAGES = COA
  MENU_PAGES {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
      entryLevel = 0
      wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            //expAll = 1
            //noBlur = 1
            target = _top
            NO = 1
            NO {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                stdWrap.innerWrap = <span>|</span> 
                allWrap = <li class="list1">|
            }

          CUR = 2
          CUR {
            stdWrap.innerWrap = <span>|</span> 
            allWrap = <li class="list1 active">|
          }
        }
      2 = TMENU
      2 {
          wrap = <a href="#" class="hasSub"></a><ul class="dropdown">|</ul></li>
          target = _top

          NO {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            }
            CUR < .NO
            CUR = 1
            CUR {
                allWrap = <li class="subactive">|</li>
            }
            ACT < .CUR
           ACT = 1
        }
    }
}
```

In this second part, only subpages of the current page are shown in the menu. As I mentioned above I need all the parent pages and their child appear in my menu. I tried  **entryLevel = -1**  but nothing happened!

Comment: First of all, the commenting in TypoScript is a `#`. `//` like you used, does not work.

Comment: yes it works, but that`s not the point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be help you:

```
lib.navbar = COA
lib.navbar.wrap = <nav>|</nav>
lib.navbar {
    special = directory
    special.value = 1

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul class="nav sf-menu">|</ul>
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap >
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        ACT = 1
        ACT < .NO
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        CUR = 1
        CUR < .NO
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    }
    2<.1
    2.wrap = <ul class="submenu">|</ul>
}
```

This is the same as you want. on hover will display sub-pages of the current page if exist. you have to change wrapping as per your requirement.

Comment: where am I suposed to put this "lib.navbar" ( I am not using fluid template) ?

Comment: In the header portion where exactly you want to show menu. you can use <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.navbar" /> to render menu. basically in your fluid template.

Comment: Is there a way to use it directly with subparts, as I am not using fluid templates in this website?

Comment: You means to say you only need sub page of the parent page?

Comment: I need pages in header menu and when i hover the mouse over the page (in the menu) to show the subpages, if you get what I am saying! I have created a template in the root page and use this template in all pages, but looks like the 'entryLevel = 0' doesn't gets the root page directly.

Comment: I have short out ts. change the wrapping and add your css class. its quite simple.